# 3divs with internal margin

Tags: html, margin

I want three divs with internal margin (without padding) like below:

```
+---------------------+
|         15px        |
| +-----------------+ |
| |       20px      | |
| | +-------------+ | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | +-------------+ | |
| +-----------------+ |
+---------------------+
```

I used following style to three divs:

```
#outer{
 width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
 position: absolute;
}
#middle{
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#inner{
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

by the above style, excluding inner div, margin works well and positions properly. But If I place inner div, then the margin-top becomes the margin of inner most div like this:

```
+---------------------+
|         20px        |
| +-----------------+ |
| | +-------------+ | |
| | |             | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | |             | | |
| | +-------------+ | |
| +-----------------+ |
+---------------------+
```

i.e, margin-top of middle div also increases from 15px to 20px (which is actually margin-top of inner div), even if I give position: relative to inner div.
I can accomplish the desired margin by applying padding to middle div (padding-top: 20px). But I want to accomplish these margins without padding.
So if I want to do that type of margins for 3, 4 or even more numbers of divs, How to do it?
Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JzUCm/, is this what you are after?

I have updated the css to this:

```
#outer{
 width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
 position: absolute;
    background:yellow;
}
#middle{
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 25px 0px 25px;
    background:red;
}
#inner{
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  top: 20px;
  left:25px;
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
}
```

Essentially I made the 3rd div absolutely positioned relative to the parent (middle div). Also disregard the background colors, only added them so you can see what's happening.

Comment: If I create a 4th div inside inner div, then the position of 4th div will be again relative, right?